# PHP(SQL) Array Passing to JS using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

New to Web development and multiple scripting languages and how they mesh together...

I'm looking to return the entire SQL table (or a subset of it) from PHP and iterate through the values in JS and can't quite get it to work any help is appreciated.

In PHP encoding the array like this.

```
//get SQL data

$return_arr[] = array("id" => $id, "otherinfo" => $otherinfo);
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

The ajax code I have looks like this but is where I'm getting tripped up...

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'example.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { i: i },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) 
    {
        for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++)
        {
            var info = response[i].otherinfo;

            var title = document.createElement("div");
            var titletext = document.createTextNode(titledb);
            title.appendChild(info);
        }
    }
)}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to include the actual issue? Where are you stuck? Making the request? Returning the correct response? Handle the response? Errors in the console? It helps if we know where to start looking.

Comment: You have a typo. The last `)}` are backwards. It should be `})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a syntax mistake.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'example.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { i: '' },
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(response)
        {

            // code here

        }

    }) // <--- here
```